# Thread blocked when calling dynamoDB in vert.x app

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, vert.x

I am using vert.x and I am trying to list my DynamoDB tables. Here is how I build the DynamoDB client.

```
private static DynamoDbAsyncClient buildDynamoDBAsyncClient(final Vertx vertx) {
        return VertxSdkClient.withVertx(DynamoDbAsyncClient.builder(), vertx.getOrCreateContext())
                .build();
    }
```

And here is the request I make

```
CompletableFuture<ListTablesResponse> response = client.listTables(ListTablesRequest.builder()
                .build());

        // Map the response to another CompletableFuture containing just the table names
        CompletableFuture<List<String>> tableNames = response.thenApply(ListTablesResponse::tableNames);

        // When future is complete (either successfully or in error) handle the response
        tableNames.whenComplete((tables, err) -> {
                if (tables != null) {
                    tables.forEach(System.out::println);
                } else {
                    // Handle error
                    err.printStackTrace();
                }
          
                client.close();
        });
        tableNames.join();
```

I get warnings of blocked threads and then a request timeout. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `tableNames.join()` blocks the thread until the operation completes. It should instead allow the `CompletableFuture` to propagate to the caller. If you include more context code, I can write a more complete answer

Comment: If the request times out resolving the Future take more time than you alwed for your request to take... dynamoDb is pretty slow so I guess you need a better query or process the stuff in the backend not inside the scope of one request if it takes several seconds to finish.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim stated in the comment, `tablesName.join()` blocks the thread, you should let the `CompletableFuture` handle async.

Try this:

```
private Future<ListTablesResponse> listTables() {
        Promise<ListTablesResponse> promise = Promise.promise();
        CompletableFuture<ListTablesResponse> response = client.listTables();

        response.handleAsync((result, error) -> {
            if (error == null) {
                promise.complete(result);
            } else {
                promise.fail(error);
            }
            return null;
        });

        return promise.future();
    }
```

then in your vertx request handler:

```
this.listTables()
        .onSuccess(listTablesResponse -> {...})
        .onFailure(throwable -> {...});
```